# ng-model seemingly not working in angularjs and ionic date picker

Tags: angularjs, ionic2, datetimepicker

I'm trying to set a default value in my ionic date picker but it just seems to be ignored.

The versions are;
Ionic "1.3.2"
Node v14.15.4
AngularJS v1.8.0
ion-datetime-picker.min.js (not sure of this version)

So far I've tried this;

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-33">
                        <strong>&nbsp;DOB: </strong>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <span ion-datetime-picker date ng-model="data.demographics.pmiDOB">
                            {{data.demographics.pmiDOB | date: "dd/MM/yyyy"}}
                       </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
$scope.data.demographics.pmiDOB = "2022-04-21"; //new Date(1974,3,24).toISOString();
```

I understand that the date picker needs an iso date format but no matter what I try the date picker when rendered just shows today's date?

Thx.

Comment: I can't even find Ionic 1 datepicker documentation using AngularJS. Most of my experience with ionic is v3+ using modern Angular. I am confused why you have a binding in the content area for your element using the ion-datetime-picker directive? Does the directive not display the current value? Also, do you have a link to the Ionic v1 docs?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any documentation either for ionic v1

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with this;

```
                let dateString = $scope.data.demographics.pmiDOB;
                let [day, month, year] = dateString.split('/')
                const dateObj = new Date(+year, +month - 1, +day)

                $scope.data.demographics.pmiDOB = dateObj;
```